# DataTable Select

Tags: asp.net

How can I use Select method of a DataTable just to fetch UserNames starting with 'M'. Lets assume that UserNameTextBox has a string **M**

```
oDataTable.Select("UserName = '" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "'");
DataView oDataView = oDataTable.DefaultView;
oDataView.Sort = "UserName";
UserGridView.DataSource = oDataView;
UserGridView.DataBind();
```

and when I typed full name into textbox, which I am sure DataTable contains, it list everything not just what I typed. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx), [`DatView.RowFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) methods or [`LINQ-to-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx):

LINQ:

```
var tblFiltered = (from row in oDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  where row.Field<String>("UserName").Contains(UserNameTextBox.Text)
                  select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

ADO.NET(DataTable.Select):

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = oDataTable.Select("UserName LIKE '%" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "%'");
```

ADO.NET(DataView.RowFilter):

```
 oDataView.RowFilter = "UserName LIKE '%" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The Select method returns a DataRow collection but won't change the DataView, you can create a DataView and set the filter string to RowFilter of the DataView, please check it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

```
DataView view = new DataView();

view.Table = oDataTable;
view.RowFilter = "UserName = '" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "'";
UserGridView.DataSource = view;
UserGridView.DataBind();
```