# using select in datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

My Datatable is in following format.

[image]

I want to get the Netfare Where Sector is 1 and then similarly I want to get Netfare Where Sector is 2.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I found a solution for you in this post [ [Link to the post][1] ]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699914/datatable-select

Comment: do you need simple sql statement or you are reading data with ADO.NET? which language you are using like c# or VB. or using Entity-framework, each has a different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataTable.Select` method to filter the result.

```
var sector1Results = dt.Select("Sector = 1");
var sector2Results = dt.Select("Sector = 2");
```

You can also use `DataTable.AsEnumerable` method to achieve the same

```
var result1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Sector") == 1).Select(x => x.Field<int>("Sector1"));

var result2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Sector") == 2).Select(x => x.Field<int>("Sector2"));
```

To select the DataRow collection, You can use this

```
List<DataRow> collection1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Sector") == 1).ToList();

List<DataRow> collection2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Sector") == 1).ToList();
```

You can also merge those condition in single statement (if you want)

```
List<DataRow> collection = new DataTable().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Sector") == 1 || x.Field<int>("Sector") == 2).ToList();
```

Comment: Can I save the result in DataRow?

Comment: Yes you can save it in DataRow but in that case you need to select the row not the single field.

Comment: Can you please tell what change should I made in the code above

Comment: It is showing  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]  on each row I used the code    List<DataRow> collection1 = DTflightoutbound.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Sector") == "1").ToList();

                    foreach (DataRow drw in DTflightoutbound.Rows)
                    {
                        drw["1 Stops"] = collection1;
                     
                    }

Comment: what do you want to achieve and what error are you facing and where?

Comment: Please check my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699791/changing-data-structure-in-data-table. This is what I want to achive

Comment: That is entirely different question from this..better to switch to that question and expect more answers..

Comment: Can you help me, how can I make changes in the Datatable. Because I need it very urgent.